# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-launcher

I am trying to run the spark application which is written in java in GKP. For the same I am able to build the image and placed in the container. But while running the spark application with spark-submit command I am facing an error which is

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
```

The java and spark versions i am using for this was jdk-11 and spark-3.2.1
I am running this application via IntelliJ with maven. Also tried adding the spark-launcher maven dependency still the issue exists.

Can I know where it is going wrong with this versions.

NOTE : I can see the spark-launcher jar in the spark-3.2.1 jar folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had that error message. It probably may have several root causes but this how I investigated and solved the problem (on linux):

- instead of launching `spark-submit`, try using `bash -x spark-submit` to
  see which line fails.
- do that process several times ( since spark-submit calls nested
  scripts ) until you find the underlying process called : in my case
  something like :

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -cp
> '/opt/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/opt/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*'
> -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main --name 'Spark shell' spark-shell

So, spark-submit launches a java process and can't find the org.apache.spark.launcher.Main class using the files in `/opt/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*` (see the -cp option above). I did an ls in this jars folder and counted 4 files instead of the whole spark distrib (~200 files). It was probably a problem during the installation process. So I reinstalled spark, checked the jar folder and it worked like a charm.

So, you should:

- check the java command (cp option)
- check your jars folder ( does it contain ths at least all the
  spark-*.jar

?)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried removing spark and re-installing it which results in same error.  I also make use of bash -x and it is showing issue in spark-class script file at LAUNCHER_EXIT_CODE line.